# Recommendations for using the for command to get different numbers as inputs from for command

Tags: python

I’ve have just started to learn python and wanted to know if there was a way to, by using the command `for` obtaining an `x` amount of inputs that I can use to do a formula. I’ve tried using

```
for i in range(x):#n=number_of_inputs_I-want
    x = int(input())
```

My problem relies in the fact that I don’t know how to make the computer store these inputs in different variables so that I can use them for a math formula. thank you for all the help you may provide.

Comment: don't store in different variables but use `list` (eventually `dict`) - and later you can use another `for`-loop to make calculation on all values. OR you can use existing function which work with list - ie. `total = sum(your_list)`. `mean = sum(your_list)/len(your_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for your question, but here is one:

```py
x = 5
x_list = []
for _ in range(x):
    val = input()
    x_list.append(val)
```